# UIView transitionWithView is smooth when using changes outside of animation block

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, reloaddata

I am reloading the data of a UITableview because the number of rows, sections and row heights change dramatically. To soften the transition I opted for the transition below when tapping a button. If I place the reloadData and/or the content offset code inside the animation block the result is "hacky"/"stuttering". If I place the view changes before the animation it works like a dream. 
Why does this work? Am I using a buggy behaviour of the transitionWithView (iOS 10.1). How should this be done correctly?

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [self.tableView contentSize].height + [self.tableView contentInset].bottom - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
[self.tableView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];

[UIView transitionWithView: self.tableView
                          duration: 0.35f
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations: ^(void)
                        {
                        }
                        completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

transitionWithView is commonly used to change the whole view of the screen, not display changes in some parts of it.
Like Apple says:

> A transition animation swaps the contents of one view controller for the contents of another.

so in most cases, to work with simple animations it is recommended to use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion]
```

or also there is another way to animate your views

```
[UIView beginAnimations:(nullable NSString *) context:(nullable void *)]
//place your view changes here to animate it
//......
[UIView commitAnimations]
```

Also there is a method that tableView has

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(nonnull NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *) withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)]
```

with number of options you can choose to animate adding new data to your tableView. So basically, you add new data to the array of objects you display in table view and then you call this method to display changes you've made.
On the other hand, you can try another method

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
//make some changes
[tableView endUpdates];
```

In those two cases above you don't need to call [tableView reloadData], because they do all work themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However the issue is that animateWithDuration does not work smoothly at all (jumps up and own probably due to content offset, rather than just fading in and out, like the crossdisolve does. If I use transitionWithView, and set the view to tableview, or just the controllers view, it works well, when excluding the changes in the animations block. Any ideas?

Comment: @damcify edited with some new approaches. hope some of them helps you with your problem